# Infertility mikvah segula

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, segulah, infertility

Is there a source of a segula to help infertility of going to mikva immediately after a pregnant woman in her ninth month?

Comment: Why do you think there might be such a source? Do you know that this is a segula? How?